# How can I parse a Date from a string and keep it in its format?

Tags: java

I have this code to convert a string to a date. but the resulting date is always in another format.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
        try {
            String dateString  = "18/01/2013 11:59";
            dateTest = format.parse(dateString);
            System.out.println(dateTest); //output: Tue Jan 18 11:59:00 GMT 2013
           }
```

How can I make it so that `dateTest` is in the same format as the original?

Comment: You can't. You're basically just printing the result of `dateTest.toString()`. [See javadoc for the fixed format which you're seeing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString()). Just use `format.format(dateTest)` to get a string in the same format back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
System.out.println(format.format(dateTest));
```

will do the job. You can use the `format()` method of your `SimpleDateFormat` to format the output the same way your input should be.

Comment: guess he needs java.util.Date in such format, however it aint possible though

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR what do you mean? `dateTest` should be a `java.util.Date`, since it was created by the `format()` method of `SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: what i mean is, he probably wanted java.util.Date in "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" fomat(not a string which Simpledateformat.format(date) returns), ASFAIK it isn't possible to output java.util.Date in such format.  format.format(dateTest) returns a String, not a java.util.Date, in simple sense i support your answer :)

Comment: OK, misunderstood you :) Well, a Date does not have a format at all, it's just an object with some fields. He can represent it (output) according to a specified format.

Answer (score 3):

Format the date using the same SimpleDateFormat you used to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because a Date does not have a 'format'.

If you need this, you could create your own Date class that contains a built-in format, but it'd be icky.

The normal way is to format the date as you print it.

```
 System.out.println(format.format(dateTest));
```

Answer (score 1):

Both java.util.Date and java.sql.Date store seconds and year, that's why you're seeing them when you print dateTest. If you want print the date in the format you provided (dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm) you simply need to format the date.

```
Date dateTest;      
SimpleDateFormat desiredDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");

try
{
    String dateString  = "18/01/2013 11:59";
    dateTest = desiredDateFormat.parse(dateString);

    System.out.println(desiredDateFormat.format(dateTest)); //output: 18/01/2013 11:59
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When outputting, use:

`System.out.println(format.format(dateTest));`